# SQLite on iOS...alter table IF?

Tags: ios, sqlite

I have inherited an existing iOS app codebase and have been told to alter a sqlite table but not use versioning (as in not just store a constant somewhere in the app that dictates how/whether to update the table). Is there a way to check whether a column exists and add that column if it doesn't exist without versioning?

Answer (score 0):

Use SQLite's [`pragma table_info()`](http://sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_table_info) to get a result set that includes one row per table. For example:

```
create table foo (bar text, baz text)
```

and

```
pragma table_info('foo')
```

That returns a two row result set:

```
[cid: 0, pk: 0, notnull: 0, name: bar, type: text, dflt_value: <null>]
[cid: 1, pk: 0, notnull: 0, name: baz, type: text, dflt_value: <null>]
```

So, perform `pragma table_info('table')` and then iterate through the rows returned and see if a row with a `name` value equal to the column you're looking for exists.